# How to stack a parent div above a div whilst it's child has a higher z-index than both?

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble with z-index in that I need a child element to have a higher z-index than it's parent, whilst the parent element still needs to be higher than the div above it.

I have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3w5dt/15/) to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve I'm almost there but can't seem to get the `scrolling-container` to scroll up and over the `fixed-container`.

**Udate: Important...**
I've tried making it `position:absolute;` and `position:relative;` which works but seems to break the z-index for the `site-nav` div, which needs to scroll over everything including the logo/links.

I'm hoping a new pair of eyes will be able to see what I'm doing wrong, so any help would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="fixed-header-container">
    <div class="logo">logo</div>
    <div class="links">links</div>
</div>

<div class="fixed-container">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/599903869980823553/sNBE6oOk_400x400.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="scrolling-container">
    <div class="site-nav"> Site Nav</div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla venenatis quis elit facilisis consequat. Nunc libero nisi, sollicitudin     quis iaculis eget...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fixed-header-container { 
    position:fixed !important; 
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 15;
}

.fixed-container { 
    height:auto; 
    position:fixed !important; 
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.logo {
    background-color: red;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.links {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
}

img {
    max-width:100%;
}

.scrolling-container {
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    background: pink;
    z-index:10;
}

.site-nav {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:40;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: When scrolling, the site nav seems to be on top of the logo.  I don't think I fully understand.  Do you want the site nav to stick to the top?

Comment: Hi sorry this is a little hard to explain. Everything is scrolling how I want except i need the `scrolling-container` to scroll up and over the `fixed-container` i.e. the image. But the scrolling container should still go behind the logo/links. Does that make sense?

Comment: Got it.  Looks like CBRoe got it below.

Comment: That was something I tried but positioning the scrolling-container ends up breaking the z-index for the `site-nav` that needs to scroll over everything including the logo/links. Any ideas how I might be able to achieve this? Or if it's even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z-index` works on positioned elements only. Your `.scrolling-container` is not positioned.

```
.scrolling-container {
    position:relative;
    /* … rest of your styles */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3w5dt/16/

---

Since you need the `.site-nav` to go above the fixed element on top as well, you could take it out of `.scrolling-container`, and then give it the same `margin-top`, as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/3w5dt/17/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but adding a position to the scrolling container breaks the z-index for the `site-nav` div (thats inside the scrolling-containert) The `site-nav` needs to be above everything.

Comment: I originally had position: absolute but then I couldn't get the `site-nav` div to have a z-index higher than everything including the logo/links. Is there a way to get both working.

Comment: Take `.site-nav` out of `.scrolling-container` (and use a different way to make them both keep their initial distance from `.fixed-container`, such as setting an appropriate margin-top or padding-top on a common container element, or specifying an appropriate `top` position for the nav.)

Comment: Could you show an example of what you mean? Do you see this to be the only option as it's difficult due to my set up to take that div outside of the scrolling container when I need it to be positioned there from the off.

Comment: Simpy adding the same margin-top to `.site-nav` as you are already adding to `.scrolling-container` would work: http://jsfiddle.net/3w5dt/17/

Comment: This may work but due to my setup may cause issues, I'll let you know how I get on. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Your last comment worked for me if you update your answer I'll accept it as it helped with what I needed. Thanks again.

Comment: OK, I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `position: relative;` on .scrolling-container.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as I explained below I originally had position: absolute but then I couldn't get the `site-nav` div to have a z-index higher than everything including the logo/links. Is there a way to have both?